# How to partition table by date dynamically?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Currently, I have a table with approximately 4 million rows, but I'd like to keep only just the last three months of data in the last partition, when this data becomes 91 days, old it should be removed from this partition and send to another partition or table.

For example,

1. Partition 0: Just keep the last three months of data in this partition (keep all current data where  DateOrder DATE_DIFF (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTHS, NOW())  )
2. Partition 1: The rest of the data from the table (keep all the data that is more than 3 months old from the current timestamp. ( DateOrder < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTHS)

```sql
CREATE TABLE LargeTable  
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,   CustomerName    VARCHAR(100)
,   CustomerEmail   VARCHAR(50)
,   DateOrder       DATETIME NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Noway. Simply move rows of the partition which is completely old to archive table then remove this partition then create new partition for future period. Perform this each quarter from event procedure. Your table finally will contain the rows which are somewhere not more than 91-120 days old.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(DateOrder))` and use weekly partitions.  This would be about 15 partitions, which is a nice balance between speed and space.

A lot more of the specific details for such are in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

300K rows is not a lot; the `DROP PARTITION` will be quite fast once a week.

Surely there are other columns and/or indexes?